# R read.table columns shifted to the left

Tags: r, fill, read.table

I created a file called test2.txt with the following information:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    A    B 
2    A    B 
3    A    B 
4    A    B 
5    A    B 
6    A    B 
7    A         C
8    A         C
```

When reading with the following command:

```
test.ws=read.table(paste(inputDir,'test2.txt',sep=''),fill=T,header=T)
```

I get the following:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    A    B   NA
2    2    A    B   NA
3    3    A    B   NA
4    4    A    B   NA
5    5    A    B   NA
6    6    A    B   NA
7    7    A    C   NA
8    8    A    C   NA
```

The columns are shifted to the left. What gives?!

I tried the following:

```
> count.fields(paste(inputDir,'test.txt',sep=''))
[1] 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4
```

And it's telling me that the number of tabs is different, but it isn't! What am I to do with this information? It's worth a mention that, when importing this .txt file into Excel, it reads the tabs correctly and doesn't skip or shift any columns.

I tried to do this assigning column names separately, but that didn't work:

```
colNames=names(test.ws)
test.ws=read.table(paste(inputDir,'test2.txt',sep=''),skip=1,fill=T,header=T,col.names=colNames)
```

Yields:

```
Warning message:
In read.table(paste(inputDir, "test2.txt", sep = ""), skip = 1,  :
  header and 'col.names' are of different lengths
```

I found a similar issue online: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-July/166676.html. That question wasn't answered.

Comment: I think it is shifted. Look at the .txt file that I'm giving to R. It clearly has four columns on rows 7 and 8. But when I read.table it into R, the fourth column simply NA's, and the fourth column on rows 7 and 8 is shifted leftward.

Comment: If the column separator is just white space, how could R possibly know that the white space in the last few rows is supposed to contain an empty column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that is tab separated data, set the separator accordingly: `sep="\t"`.  Otherwise (from the help on `read.table`)

> If `sep = ""` (the default for read.table) the separator is ‘white space’, that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage returns.

and so multiple consecutive tabs are being treated as a single delimiter.

Or use `read.delim` instead of `read.table` as that has defaults better suited for tab-separated data.

Comment: Bingo! I could swear that I did that, but I was apparently thinking of the sep in paste(). This is embarrassing...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have fixed width columns?

```
read.fwf(textConnection("col1 col2 col3 col4
1    A    B 
2    A    B 
3    A    B 
4    A    B 
5    A    B 
6    A    B 
7    A         C
8    A         C"),widths = rep(5,4))

     V1    V2    V3   V4
1 col1  col2  col3  col4
2 1     A        B  <NA>
3 2     A        B  <NA>
4 3     A        B  <NA>
5 4     A        B  <NA>
6 5     A        B  <NA>
7 6     A        B  <NA>
8 7     A              C
9 8     A              C
```